# res.redirect não redireciona no expressjs

Tags: node.js, redirecionamento, express.js

Estou o nodejs juntamente com o expressjs e na submissão de um formulário é feita uma requisição no servidor, que depois de tratada, redireciona a página:

```
...

Post.create(doc, (err, post) => {
    if (err || !post) {
        return res.json({
            status: 'error',
            error: err
        });
    }
    post.save()

    res.redirect('/minha-url')
});
...
```

Mas o redirecionamento não é feito, apesar de que no painel devTools do Chrome, na aba networking o redirecionamento aparece com status 200, como uma requisição.

Não entendo qual pode ser o problema.

Agradeço a qualquer ajuda.

Comment: Estás a fazer um post com o `action` de um formulário? Podes juntar o HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava a fazer o post a partir de ajax e não de um form. Com isso, ao invés de user o `res.redirect('route')`, apenas recebi a rota do servidor e usei no lado do cliente um

```
window.location = route;
```

para redirecionar.